# uploadifive select files, nothing happens

Tags: php, uploadify

I've already read many posts on this subject, but none had an answer that works for me.

I'm using uploadifive to upload images. When I select a file, and click `open`, nothing happens. I get no errors in my console, or when I use `onError` from uploadifive it self, it also gives me nothing. The `onSelect` gives me this:

> count: 1, selected: 1, replaced: 0, errors: 0 , queued: 1

The `onUpload` alerts me that there is one file to upload. So I guess it does select the file, but it just won't upload. The `uploadScript` also doesn't appear in my console/network, so it seems to not even fire that part.

The even weirder part is that I've used uploadifive in another part of my website and there it works fine. But when I copy the code to another part, it doesn't work.

Do I miss something or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: my code (i've put in every single one function that uploadifive has to see which ones fires and which one doesn't)

```
$('#mediafile_upload').uploadifive({
'uploadScript'          : '/mediafiles/uploadimage', //waar hij heen gaat
'buttonText'            : '+ Toevoegen',
'width'                 : '140',
'height'                : '100',
'dnd'                   : true,
'multi'                 : true,
'removeCompleted'       : true,
'queueID'               : false,

'onUpload'     : function(filesToUpload) {
    alert(filesToUpload + ' files will be uploaded.');
},
'onAddQueueItem' : function(file) {
    console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' was added to the queue!');
},
'onCancel'     : function() {
    console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' was cancelled!');
},
'onCheck'      : function(file, exists) {
    if (exists) {
        console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' exists on the server.');
    }
},                  
'onClearQueue' : function(queue) {
    queue.css('border', '2px solid #F00');
},  
'onDestroy'    : function() {
    console.log('Oh noes!  you destroyed UploadiFive!');
},          
'onDrop'       : function(file, fileDropCount) {
    console.log(fileDropCount + ' files were dropped onto the queue.');
},              
'onError'      : function(errorType) {
    console.log('The error was: ' + errorType);
},              
'onInit'       : function() {
    console.log('Add files to the queue to start uploading.');
},              
'onProgress'   : function(file, e) {
    console.log('onprogress file: ' + file);
    console.log('onprogress e: ' + e);
},
'onQueueComplete' : function(uploads) {
    console.log(uploads.successful + ' files were uploaded successfully.');
},       
'onSelect' : function(queue) {
    console.log(queue.queued + ' files were added to the queue.');
},      
'onUpload'     : function(filesToUpload) {
    console.log(filesToUpload + ' files will be uploaded.');
},       
'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
    console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' uploaded successfully.');
},
'onUploadFile' : function(file) {
    console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' is being uploaded.');
}        

});
```

This is what my console says:
[image: screenshot console]

Comment: you should post the relevant portions of the code

Comment: Thanks, I saw your edit but I didn't know how to chose it, so I added your improvements myself. Thanks, it definitely better readable now!

Comment: Could you make the following steps:  switch to you `Network` tab, reload your page, then try to upload a document, you should see a request to `/mediafiles/uploadimage` with method `POST` if it is there please tell which status code this request has.

Comment: There is no `/mediafiles/uploadimage` post or anything. It's like the `uploadScript` is never fired...

Comment: Are there any `4xx` or `5xx` status messages in the `Network` tab ? (I did an exact copy & past of your javascript code and here it works, so it must be some loading issue i think, or a conflict with another script)

Comment: No there is nothing. This is what I do: I reload, clear the loaded pages/scripts/etc., then make sure the record button is on, then I click the upload button, select my file, click on open, and nothing happens. There is no page loaded in my network, what so ever.

Sorry didn't see your second part. The exactly same code works by you? So then I need to find the error outside of uplaodfive somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of answered my own question. I have know idea how, but if I don't use the jquery-uploadifive.js file but the jquery-uploadify.min.js file, it works! The strange part is that I haven't changed a thing in the unminified version.. but well it works. Thanks everyone for helping.